# Jquery ajax returns nothing

Tags: laravel

Hello I am trying to pull data using ajax but from my surprise nothing is showing,I set my controller and object correct because when i test the url on the browser I can see data.Here is my ajax code(I am using laravel framework)

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "{{action('TestController@getCampignDaily')}}/"+127
        }).done(function(resultTwo){


    });
```

127 is the id, i am sure that it has something
here is the output of 127 if i test on the browser

```
   array (size=20)
   'campaignId' => int 127
   'advertiserId' => int 91
   'campaignName' => string 'Justin Campaign' (length=15)
   'startDate' => 
   object(stdClass)[426]
      public 'scalar' => string '20150421T00:00:00' (length=17)
      public 'xmlrpc_type' => string 'datetime' (length=8)
      public 'timestamp' => int 1429574400
  'endDate' => 
  object(stdClass)[428]
    public 'scalar' => string '20150423T00:00:00' (length=17)
    public 'xmlrpc_type' => string 'datetime' (length=8)
    public 'timestamp' => int 1429747200
  'impressions' => int -1
  'clicks' => int 100
  'priority' => int 3
  'weight' => int 0
  'targetImpressions' => int 0
  'targetClicks' => int 100
  'targetConversions' => int 0
  'revenue' => float 8
  'revenueType' => int 2
  'capping' => int 0
  'sessionCapping' => int 0
  'block' => int 0
  'comments' => string 'Enter campaign description' (length=26)
  'viewWindow' => int 0
  'clickWindow' => int 0
```

Comment: jQuery ajax has a "done" event and it also has an "error" event

Comment: chrome dev tools -> network tab, then trigger the ajax call and see the url it is calling and what is returned.

Comment: @flauntster Remote Address:[::1]:8000
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/test/campign-daily/127
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax request expects json format (`dataType`) and browser output you showed does not look like a json.

```
return response()->json($yourData, 200);
```

(Laravel 5)